# Update a record or insert if it doesn't exists, with locking

Tags: mysql, concurrency, locking, innodb

I would like to update a record if exists. Thats the easiest part, but that record may not exist, so let's create it first. Pseudocode:

```
UPDATE x SET y=1 WHERE id=5
```

if the result of it is 0, then...

```
a, LOCK TABLE x
b, INSERT INTO...
c, UNLOCK TABLE x
```

But I cant find a concrete tutorial. I suppose the step A must be "true" if locking was successfull, and "false" if already locked. But its always true, in case of simultenaously running.

(Ps: I know there are replace into and those kind of operations, but this time this is just what I need)

Comment: Use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`. This is automatically in a transaction so you don't need locking.

Comment: Don't use `LOCK TABLE`, use a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should use a transaction or `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICAGTE UPDATE ...`.

But if you really have to use locking, you have to put both `UPDATE` and `INSERT` within the locked region.

```
LOCK TABLE x;
UPDATE x SET y = 1 WHERE id = 5;
IF FOUND_ROWS() = 0 
THEN
    INSERT INTO x (id, y) VALUES (5, 1);
END IF
UNLOCK TABLE x;
```

Comment: Don't encourage `LOCK TABLE`.  Do encourage (as you did in a Comment) the use of IODKU.

Comment: I've added the recommendation to the answer.